# Ubiquity appears to hang installing dual boot OSX

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro, ubiquity

I am trying to dual-boot OSX (10.9 Mavericks) and Ubuntu 14.04, and the Ubiquity installer has apparently hung for the last 20 minutes.

I resized my OSX partition using Disk Utility in OSX, and made a FAT partition there.  Then in Ubuntu from the Live USB I ran the installer.  Resized this partition a bit (screenshot) and confirmed.  After that, nothing.

There's a fatal error in the Ubiquity-dm log seemingly related to some X session not existing.  Not entirely sure if this is relevant.

Ubiquity version 2.18.17.

[image: screen shot showing ubiquity partition config and top from temrinal]

## Some log files

### /var/log/installer/debug

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tail -f /var/log/installer/debug 
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 332438 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 346649 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 346742 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 347267 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 347407 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

### /var/log/installer/dm

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tail -f /var/log/installer/dm 
(panel:2083): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_remove_accelerator: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACCEL_GROUP (accel_group)' failed
ubiquity-dm: greeter exited with code 0
nm-applet-Message: PID 1987 (we are 2105) sent signal 15, shutting down...

(process:2086): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
(EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
ubiquity-dm: set_locale
ubiquity-dm: Exiting with code 0
```

Comment: Did your partitions get resized? Do you see any errors related to parted? Can you check the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` and `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. It might be best to do your repartitioning in OS X and then in Ubuntu choose manual install and just assign / (so parted does not need to do any shifting or resizing)

Comment: why don't you make a different partition for ubuntu and then install it

Comment: @bain Yeah I did the initial partitioning in OSX, then switch to Ubuntu to repartition th empty partition, or at least I attempted to.  `gdisk` shows a partition called LINUX, so I'm assuming it did the partitioning.  `fdisk` shows the same partition on `/dev/sda4`.

Comment: @Creator Yeah I think this is what I will do.  I just took the defaults from the ubiquity QUI because the partition looked like the right size.  I suppose it's just save to reboot in this state?

Comment: @sennett -So I take this to be the answer

Comment: You might want to run `fixparts` to check that your GPT/MBR tables are in a consistent state.

Comment: @Creator yes I needed to delete the partition created in OSX and create swap and root FS manually.  Thanks for your help.  Write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @bain Thanks for your input.  The patition tool did not run correctly under the default options I don't think.  I could still see the partitions in fdisk and gdisk, and when I rebooted I could manually partition with no issues.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seperate partition for ubuntu installation and install Ubuntu on it. Reboot and install ubuntu to create a live media in order to Install Ubuntu  on your system, also delete the partiton
created in OSX and merge that space with the Ubuntu partition using Gparted.

You can get help on ubuntu installation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX)

and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To)